# JSF + JPA without EJB or Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jpa, ejb

I need to make simple CRUD web app (i'll get paid for it), but i don't have any experience in java web development, so i have a few questions just to get going.

As far as i understand there's 2 ways to do it: using pure **javaee** with ejb and glassfish server; using **spring** in any other container. The problem is i don't quite understand those technologies and don't have much time to learn. So I've found this http://wrschneider.blogspot.com/2011/09/jsf-jpa-without-ejb-or-spring.html and http://www.swview.org/blog/best-way-use-jpa-web-tier. Looks perfect for my first app.

Is this going to work for me?

Please have a look at the links i posted. What do you think about them? Thats my question.

Comment: And what is your comfort level with Java, Web development and SQL ? These will be crucial before you can decide on anything.

Comment: i have some experience with ORM frameworks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If this really going to be a simple CRUD app, I would suggest you to use plain JSF or JSP with JPA. EJB and Spring are really not easy to learn, so I would stay away from them. Also you can try some other framework which may simplify this for you(like Play).

And I if you will avoid EJB, I would suggest you to swich to Tomcat application server, it's more lightweight and easier to run and configure(and it's everything what you need in JSF/JSP project)

Comment: I think, also JSF/JSP its no good solution to start from. In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204803/java-based-framework-for-web-applications-for-beginners I asked a question about this topic. I think, one of the suggestions made there would be much better for a bloody beginner.

Comment: Play framework seems to be as a nice project but if he going to learn developing Jave EE apps little bit more then at some poing he will have to start with one of the "bigger" technologies. And in my opinion JSF is best choice(especially in 2.0 version), it's not so hard to learn and laso widely used standard.

Comment: Thanks for response. Please have a look at links in original question. What do you think about them?

Comment: For the start is not bad, but it doesn't cover much. So if you want to try JSF, check out this one http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/index.html, is also contains tutorial for Primefaces JSF library which offers more components and far more better Ajax support then pure JSF.

Comment: I don't agree with this, EJB is very easy to learn!

Comment: Yes, but there is still a lot thinks to learn and I don't think it's necessary to do that for simple CRUD app. So thats why I adviced to start with JSF. And then he can move to EJB if he will keeps his interest Java EE.

Comment: I cannot judge about others learning curve. I argue, that not using EJBs (SessionBeans) does increase your LOC. E.g. @PersistenceContext injects the instantiated EnitityManger. Without, you need to instantiate it yourself. At lease 10 extra lines of code. There are more of these examples. On the other hand an extra EJB class has to be written, but you can harness the auto-instantiaton and auto-transaction service. Thus, I recommend using JSF (View), CDI-Bean/ManagedBean (View/Controller), SessionBean (Controller) and Entity Bean (Model) to establish the MVC or MVP Pattern.

Comment: Sure, but it's still a new whole technology to learn so that's why I suggested to play around with CDI and JSF and then move on to EJB or something else...And I still believe that EJBs with application server are overkill for small CRUD app.

Answer (score -1):

I dont want to be rude, but are you sure you want to do this with a technology you have no clue about?

I think there are a lot more frameworks that are simpler to use then JSF/JPA/EJB/Spring. For instance have a look at [Play](http://www.playframework.org/). I think it will take short time to have first CRUD pages.

Comment: did you mean "no **clue** about" ;-) ?

Comment: Stick around with the technology you know, even if it is not perfect. ^^

Comment: Why?If this is going to be a simple app and he is willing to learn something new then some other technology is worth to try. At least this is the way I am doing it:-)

Comment: Thanks for response. Please have a look at links in original question. What do you think about them?

Comment: If you have some basic understanding of the concepts behind JSF/JPA/EJB/Spring then these two articles gives a good hint about to use only JSF/JPA. 

But it addresses only a very small part of your whole application. You still have to do a lot things - mastering the whole java part, starting and configuring and running an application server, understand and use the persistence api,... As I said before - using a newbie friendly framework like Play lets you concentrate on your business logic and hides much of the complexity.